# FactoryGirl for models with inheritance where parent and child have associations

Tags: inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a typical inheritance pattern, but the parent has an association to another model and the children do also have associations to other models.

```
class MyBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game, inverse_of: :my_base
  validates :game, presence: true
end

class Child < MyBase
  self.table_name = 'children'
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :child
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

I know that I can tell factory girl to use a specific class but when I use the child class as constructor, it can't create the association for the parent class and vica versa.

```
  factory :child, class: MyBase, parent: :my_base do
    association :user, strategy: :build
  end
```

This gives me *invalid factory* when linted:

`child - can't write unknown attribute 'user_id' (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)`

How do I need to set up my factory that both associations will be created?

PS: This is a multi table inheritance situation.

Comment: Might this occur because the factory girl linter is using the active record table definitions to lint and is not taking the connections on the application level into account?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by using the child class as the "class" name:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :child, class: Child, parent: :my_base do
    association :owner, factory: :user, strategy: :build
  end
end
```